# PaintContext: Unable to clip child with rounded corners

Tags: flutter

Why does the `drawColor` (#1) call get clipped, but the `paintChild` (#2) does not? This is within a `paint` method of a `RenderSliverSingleBoxAdapter` subclass.

```
context.clipRRectAndPaint(
    RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
        offset & Size(paintBounds.width, paintBounds.height + 100.0),
        topLeft: Radius.circular(topCornerRadius),
        topRight: Radius.circular(topCornerRadius)),
    Clip.antiAlias,
    paintBounds, () {

  // 1
  context.canvas.drawColor(Colors.blue, BlendMode.srcOver);

  // 2
  context.paintChild(child, offset);
});
```

Comment: Is this only with an emulator, a real device, or with both?

Comment: Happens for both...